I'm looking for a way to fix Windows 11 without a full reinstall. In Windows 11, the installed voice packages in settings are showing up as 0mb
I'm looking for a way to fix my Window's 11 install as 2 of my voice packages aren't working properly. I've googled lots, asked Chat GPT and tried everything I know so far.
Is there is a way to fix the installed voice packages without having to reinstall Windows? I don't know what is causing the problem but this is the second time this has happened to me and it take about 3 days to set up my computer perfectly with all the programs I need after a full reinstall. I'm using both English and Japanese on my PC.
The settings area says the voice packages are 0mb. Software like Deepl and other text to speech programs don't work properly because the files are maybe corrupt.
I think I've tried most of the standard ways of fixing the packages.
I've tried an in place reinstall of Windows.
I tried removing the voice packages manually but the remove buttons were greyed out.
I've tried using PowerShell and Command Prompt to try lots of different combinations of uninstalling and installing the packages but I can't seem to fix the installs.
I can't even get the packages to disappear from the setting area.
Examples of code I've tried:
sfc /scannow
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

DISM /Online /Get-Capabilities

Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name "Language.Basic~~~en-US~0.0.1.0"
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name "Language.Handwriting~~~en-US~0.0.1.0"
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name "Language.Speech~~~en-US~0.0.1.0"

DISM /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Speech.TTS.en-US
DISM /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Speech.TTS.ja-JP

Remove-WindowsCapability -Online -Name "Speech.TTS.en-US"
Remove-WindowsCapability -Online -Name "Speech.TTS.ja-JP"

Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name "Speech.TTS.en-US"
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name "Speech.TTS.ja-JP"

Regedit to remove tokens and reinstall them
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech_OneCore\Voices\Tokens

I even manually moving folders with data and tried to reinstall them. The data was put back after trying this though.
I've even tried modifying the GPO, etc.
Open the group policy editor on your domain
Run + gpedit.msc
Create a new GPO, or modify an existing one. Make sure it applies to the computers you’d like
Navigate to “Computer Configuration”, “Policies”, “Administrative Templates”, and then “System”.
Double click or open “Specify settings for optional component installation and component repair”
Make sure “Never attempt to download payload from Windows Update” is NOT checked
Make sure “Download repair content and optional features directly from Windows Update instead of Windows Server Update Services (WSUS)” IS checked.
Wait for your GPO to update, or run “gpupdate /force” on the workstations.
I can't figure out a good way to fix this so I'm seeking help.

Edition Windows 11 Pro
Version 24H2
Installed on    ‎11/‎18/‎2024 ‎Mon
OS build    26100.2454
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.26100.36.0

Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-7980XE CPU @ 2.60GHz   2.60 GHz
Installed RAM   64.0 GB (63.7 GB usable)
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

"the files are maybe corrupt." - If DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth and sfc /scannow are not detecting the files are corrupt then they are not actually corrupt. If you spin up a Windows 11 VM, without any of your adjustments, and then add Speech.TTS.en-US and Speech.TTS.ja-JP are the files still 0MB?  Configuring Windows to use WSUS only works if you are actually using WSUS to update it. Are you disabling features or using any third-party applications to modify Windows or are you just installing third-party user applications? [Edit] your question to include this information
